# Please add a 'view source' link to questions and answers that have no revisions

Tags: feature-request, revisions-list, view-source

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [View Source link on all questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24400/view-source-link-on-all-questions)

I asked the following question on ServerFault:

> [How do I hide ‘non-delegated’ features in IIS 7?](https://serverfault.com/questions/119419/how-do-i-hide-non-delegated-features-in-iis-7)

Scott's answer describes a couple of xml tags that I can modify, but because he didn't use the back-tick to escape them they're hidden from view.

Because I don't have edit rights I can't open the source easily (no Edit link) to see if this indeed what was missing. After fiddling around looking around for another post that had revisions (to see how the revision list url was composed) I was eventually able to see the revision history for Scott's answer and then get at the raw markdown text via [`View Source`](https://serverfault.com/revisions/0ea400e4-d521-4783-b8fd-5b51b5f60d56/view-source):

> https://serverfault.com/posts/119803/revisions

It would be nice to either provide a link that shows the revision history for questions and answers regardless of whether they had revisions or not, or, provide a `View Source` link to allow us to see the raw Markdown on the revision of the post being rendered.

This would be a nice time saver because the `/posts/nnnnn/revisions` link doesn't immediately commit itself in memory if used infrequently.

Comment: Where did that 'can' go when I wrote this :)

Comment: +1 At first I thought, just flag it for the moderator, but why should you have to wait? It's already there.

Comment: duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24400/view-source-link-on-all-questions

Comment: @lesmana - yep you're right, well spotted because the search didn't come up with that one when I asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GreaseMonkey Script

[Install](http://userscripts.org/scripts/source/70690.user.js) - [View Source](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/70690)

[alt text http://img704.imageshack.us/img704/1535/revisionspostmenu.png](http://img704.imageshack.us/img704/1535/revisionspostmenu.png)

**Edit**: Added links to each revision (need to reinstall to take effect)

[alt text http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/8414/linkinrevisions.png](http://img691.imageshack.us/img691/8414/linkinrevisions.png)

Comment: this needs another glyph.  ;)

Comment: hmm.  also, it adds it to the post menu of the answer (which is ok, since answers have revisions too) but gives the URL of the question post (which is not, since answers have revisions too).  in the case of this answer, the revisions URL should not be http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/41391/revisions but http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/41406/revisions

Comment: Should this work in Chrome 4.0 stable (http://blog.chromium.org/2010/02/40000-more-extensions.html)? I see that it got added in the extensions manager but it doesn't add the revisions link.

Comment: Same experience as Kev, using the tip of Chrome beta.

Comment: I havn't done greasemonkey on Chrome before, but I will try to figure out.

Comment: @S.Mark - your timeline GM script puts an anchor with a triangle next to each question title but no link at all for answers. Chrome's GM support not as good as expected? DOM differences?

Comment: @Kev, timeline functions don't have seperate function for answers I think, timeline page combine all the activities on both questions and answers.

Comment: @~quack, revisions link for answers are fixed, http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/70690 , for Chrome, I need to learn how Chrome's greasemonkey is different from Firefox greasemonkey

Comment: @S.Mark - timeline - oh aye, doh.

Comment: @S.Mark - ok me being thick and realised 'triangle' is delta. :)

Comment: @S.Mark - works ok. the *if* clause strikes me as wonky; i think this is cleaner for getting the post id: `id = $(this).find("a[id^=flag-post-]").attr("id").replace("flag-post-", "");`

Comment: Ah, thanks @~quack, I just updated to very similar one, `$(this).find('a[id][id^="flag-post-"]').attr("id").match(/\d+/)[0];`, but yours looks better. I am going to use it

Comment: @S.Mark - should this work in Chrome now?

Comment: @Kev, still can't figure out, I'm looking into some other scripts.

Comment: @Kev, I can now run in Chrome too (revision script), updated, http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/70690 - if you installed once, may be you need to uninstall first.

Comment: @S.Mark -that works a treat thanks, that said I think this should be a feature of SO for those not able to use Chrome or Firefox.