# URLs with ' are not recognized in preview window

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown-preview

Examples:

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement
2. [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)
3. [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)

The original Markdown was:

```
1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement
2. [two's complement][1]
3. [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)

[1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement
```

Shows in preview (when editing) as:

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement
2. two's complement
3. two's complement

Comment: What about those of us with less than the required rep to edit?

Comment: @Josh: You can build the “revisions” URL yourself (and use “view source”) even for single revision questions/answers: `http://[sofu].com/posts/[num]/revisions` http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41391/please-add-a-view-source-link-to-questions-and-answers-that-have-no-revisions

Comment: @Chris: This question is about how it looks in the preview window when editing, not the markdown source.

Comment: @Josh: You can type the markdown into either a new question ('ask question' button at the top) or an answer (below) to see how the preview behaves.  (As far as I know, both kinds of previews should be identical.)

Comment: @The Cat: The question at the time of Josh's comment did not include the code block that showed the markup (see the [timeline](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/48975/timeline)). Also, since it only had one revision, it did not include the “edited … ago” link to the ‘revisions’ page. My comment tells how a non-editor can arrange to see the markup for a single revision post (manually construct the URL to the ‘revisions’ page; then use the “view source” link).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Workaround is using `%27` instead of `'`

```
1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement
2. [two's complement][1]
3. [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

[1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement
```

will be

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement
2. [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)
3. [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: Actually, just using [ text ]( href ) works just fine when posted, just not in the preview.

Comment: That's not even a workaround, but the required way [reserved characters should be encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters). Nice if some editors or browsers make it easy for you, but I think it's still a reserved character...

Comment: @The Cat: yes, I know that it works once it is posted. But this bug report is specifically about the preview window. @S.Mark thanks for the suggestion, but it seems rather complicated to me. I wonder why the markdown can not just be parsed in the same way as it is later parsed (when posted).

Answer (score 2):

And a quick fix could be, changing following 3 regexes from

```
/^(<a\shref="(\#\d+|(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;\(\)]+)"(\stitle="[^"<>]+")?\s?>|<\/a>)$/i

/(^|\s)(https?|ftp)(:\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|\[\]\(\)!:,\.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|\[\]])($|\W)/gi

/<((https?|ftp):[^'">\s]+)>/gi
```

to

```
/^(<a\shref="(\#\d+|(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;\(\)']+)"(\stitle="[^"<>]+")?\s?>|<\/a>)$/i

/(^|\s)(https?|ftp)(:\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|\[\]\(\)!:,\.;']*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|\[\]])($|\W)/gi

/<((https?|ftp):[^">\s]+)>/gi
```

in wmd.js

<sub>**Note**: I am not sure those could cause different flaws though :)</sub>